# Replace Part of a File Name in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have files that look like this:

2020-0517-example.pdf

2020-0412-example.pdf

2020-0607-example.pdf

I would like to rename the files to:

2020-0723-example.pdf

2020-0723-example.pdf

2020-0723-example.pdf

I would basically be replacing the dates to today's date while keeping the year and the suffix.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a bit of sanity checking to make sure you are dealing with dates, you can use pattern matching and then rename the partial date:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format MMdd
Get-ChildItem -Path <filepath> -File |
    Where Basename -match '^(?:19|20)\d\d-(?:0[1-9]|1[012])\d\d-' |
        Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?<=^\d{4}-)\d{4}',$date } -whatif
```

Alternatively, you can parse the date string first to verify it using `TryParseExact`:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format MMdd
Get-ChildItem -Path <filepath> -File |
    Where Name -match '^\d{4}-\d{4}-' | Foreach-Object {
        if ([datetime]::TryParseExact($_.Name.Substring(0,9),'yyyy-MMdd',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,[ref]0)) {
            $FileParts = $_.Name -split '-',3
            Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName ($FileParts[0],$date,$FileParts[2] -join '-') -WhatIf
       }
    }
```

You will need to remove the `-WhatIf` parameter for the rename operation to complete.

**Explanation:**

Using `-split '-',3`, we ensure that we are left with no more than three array elements. This provides a predictable number of indexes for putting the file name back together. `[0]` will be the year. `[1]` will be the month-day. `[2]` will be the remainder of the file name.

Please see the following for the `-replace` and `-match` regex details:

[Regex -Match](https://regex101.com/r/WuZIQQ/1)

[Regex -Replace](https://regex101.com/r/IgPchP/1)

Comment: I know this might be a silly question, but how do I run this I am not too familiar with code/scripts. I usually use shift / right-click and "open open PowerShell here" to run my other useful scripts

Comment: You can open a PowerShell console and paste this code. You could also put it in a `.ps1` file and run the file by typing out its fully qualified path in the console.

Comment: I was able to run it, thank you! One more thing though... I did notice it isn't changing the file if the month is 10>= for example 2020-1012 won't change to 2020-0723. How do I fix this?

Comment: @BrendanGilman, Apologies. I added that case just now.

Comment: Not a problem at all thank you for the clarification, got it to work for all now!

Answer (score 1):

You could split by `"-"` and stitch together with `String.Format`:

```
$filename = "2020-0517-example.pdf"
$today = Get-Date
$arr = $filename.Split("-")
$newname = "{0}-{1:MMdd}-{2}" -f $arr[0], $today, $arr[2]
```

Comment: I know this might be a silly question, but how do I run this I am not too familiar with code/scripts. I usually use shift / right-click and "open open PowerShell here" to run my other useful scripts

Comment: If you want a ready-to-use script, AdminOfThings answer is the way to go - I just tossed the idea of `split`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!